# development works but not in production

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I have an error when I run the below code:

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `total__quantity' for nil:NilClass):

```
error :
```

undefined method `total__quantity' for nil:NilClass

Comment: It appears as if `@orgs` does not include the element you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
@org.children.each do |child|
  if (!child.total_quantity.nil?)
    %tr
      %td.child= link_to child.shrt_name, child
```

I'm assuming that from your original post, you're accidentally omitting the `@` before `org.children.each`

I'm also not sure why you feel the need to reassign the value of `child` in  your loop.

Comment: Isn't his problem that `child` is `nil`, not that `total_quantity` returns `nil`. It says `undefined method ... for `NilClass`; `child` is `NilClass`, right?

Comment: That's part of the problem. My question is why child is being reassigned from another collection since `org` and `@orgs` are clearly different.

Comment: yes. i tried. but still ends up with error .. can you please look on to my new post which i included the full code and help me on this.

Comment: The line `child = @organizations[child.id]` confuses me. What is `@organizations` ? If it's a collection, do you mean `@organizations.find(child.id)` ?

Comment: @organizations is a table in database.

Comment: Then do you call something like this `@organizations = Organization.all` in your controller? If so, then `@organization` is a collection, like an array. `child.id` is the database id of the `Child` object. So if you have 5 organizations and 10 children, than `@organizations[child.id] also be `@organizations[10]` with a limit of 5. which is how you're getting `nil:NilClass`.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `@org` has no children. You better do this;

```
children = @org.children

unless children.empty?
   children.each do |child|
      if child.total_quantity > 0
         # Your code here
      end
   end
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @cabolanoz.. can you see my new post which i included my full code and help me on this one.